# Call class method with different class

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's assume we have the following two classes:

```
class Class1:
    def method(self):
        print("Class1.method() with self =", self)
    @classmethod
    def clsmethod(cls):
        print("Class1.clsmethod() with cls =", cls)
obj1 = Class1()

class Class2:
    def method(self):
        print("Class2.method() with self =", self)
    @classmethod
    def clsmethod(cls):
        print("Class2.clsmethod() with cls =", cls)
obj2 = Class2()
```

For normal bound methods, it is easy to inject a different self. We just have to call `Class1`'s `method()` but with `obj2` as `self`:

```
>>> Class1.method(o2)
Class1.method() with self = <__main__.Class2 object at 0x...>
```

The question is now: How can I do similar things but with classmethods?

```
>>> Class1.clsmethod(Class2)
Class1.clsmethod() with cls = <__main__.Class2 object at 0x...>
```

By what does `Class1` have to be replaced? The intuitive approach of using `type(Class1)` ("the class of `Class1`" similar to "the class of `obj1`) does not work because a class method is not a attribute of the metaclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By accessing `__func__` attribute, you can get unbound function object.

```
class Class1:
    def method(self):
        print("Class1.method() with self =", self)
    @classmethod
    def clsmethod(cls):
        print("Class1.clsmethod() with cls =", cls)

class Class2:
    def method(self):
        print("Class2.method() with self =", self)
    @classmethod
    def clsmethod(cls):
        print("Class2.clsmethod() with cls =", cls)

Class1.clsmethod.__func__(Class2)  # <----
# prints
# Class1.clsmethod() with cls = <class '__main__.Class2'>

Class2.clsmethod.__func__(Class1)  # <----
# prints
# Class2.clsmethod() with cls = <class '__main__.Class1'>
```

Comment: Oh, that was to obvious. :-[ Thank you very much!